# Pass a value from .txt to a HTML textbox (using Batch, Java, or PHP)

Tags: java, javascript, parsing, batch-file

Complex question so let me try to explain....

I have a text file (named filelist.txt) with a list of values like so:

```
12_23_4_ABC_|
12_35_6_XYZ_|
12_36_5_ABC_|
12_37_9_UVW_|
12_38_8_XYZ_|
12_39_1_ABC_|

(pipe ( | ) is the delimiter)
```

I have a HTML page (named ABCparser.html) that has a text box where I can type values and then hit "Submit", however this particular page only accepts the values that prefix `_ABC_` (there is another HTML page that accepts the `_XYZ_` and `_UVW_`), instead of me hardcoding the prefixed values in the `value = ""` portion in each time on each page, is there a way to capture it from the text file (.txt) and pass it to the HTML page? I already have a JavaScript function on the page to auto-hit the "Submit" button. I would prefer to do this in Batch if possible since my main program is written in that, or if someone could help me provide it in Java or even PHP that I could call off from Batch.

The text box code:

```
<input type="text" name="trackingId" size="100" value = "">
```

There is a catch though. I need to pass cleaned up data to the HTML text box....

So objectives:

- Parse text file and look for lines that have `_ABC_`
- If line is false go to next line in text file (see 5th bullet), if line is true take the value upto
  the third underscore and capture it to be passed to the HTML text
  box, however convert the previous underscores to dashes and separate values by commas.
- So the text box code should appear like this with the aforementioned example:

  - `<input type="text" name="trackingId" size="100" value = "12-23-4, 12-36-5, 12-39-1">`
- JavaScript function auto submits, web service call successfully made.
- If line has `_XYZ_` do the same steps but send it to the
  "XYZparser.html", if line has `_UVW_` send it to the "UVWparser.html"
- User could change the numerics in the filelist.txt at any time but the suffixes will remain constant (ie: on a later run the user may not want to submit 12_23_4_ABC_, they may want to see 13_87_1_ABC_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f "delims==" %%i IN ('set val 2^>nul') DO (SET %%i=)
FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=_" %%a IN (filelist.txt) DO (
SET val_%%d=!val_%%d!, %%a-%%b-%%c
)
FOR /f "tokens=2,3delims=_=" %%i IN ('set val 2^>nul') DO (
SET list=%%j
SET list=!list:~2!
>%%iparser.html ECHO ^<input type="text" name="trackingId" size="100" value = "!list!"^>
ECHO generated %%i parser
)
```

Five-minute task. First clear out any environment variables named VAL*, grab the list and build the strings for the VALUE data in variables `val_prefix`

When the text file has been processed, look for VAR* in the environment, grab the part following the underscore for use in the output filename, remove the first two characters of the data item, which will be comma-space and generate the line to the file. Report the production of the HTML file - can be used to trigger whatever needs to be triggered.

Took longer to document than to program...

---

Amendment for revised specification

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f "delims==" %%i IN ('set val 2^>nul') DO (SET %%i=)
FOR /f "tokens=1-5delims=_|" %%a IN (filelist.txt) DO (
 IF "%%e"=="" (SET val_%%d=!val_%%d!, %%a-%%b-%%c) ELSE (
               SET val_%%d_%%e=!val_%%d_%%e!, %%a-%%b-%%c)
)
FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims==" %%i IN ('set val 2^>nul') DO (
SET html=%%i
SET html=!html:*_=!parser.html
SET list=%%j
SET list=!list:~2!
>!html! ECHO ^<input type="text" name="trackingId" size="100" value = "!list!"^>
ECHO generated !html!
)
```

Nearly the same as OP's version. Minor difference in the setting of `%%e`, but that's a matter of style.

Simpler method of generating the HTML files though - with a bit of sneakiness. The `FOR` simply splits the name from the value. Dealing with the name, it will be of the format `val_something` so applying it to a variable (string operations can't be performed directly on metavariables) then `!html:*_=!` will take `var_something` and change all of the characters up to and including the first `_` (the character or string between the `*` and `=`) to those characters after the `=` - which in this case is nothing, so the leading `..._` is deleted (well, OK, since we know that all `var..` variables will start `var_` we could just as easily have used `!html:~4!` - matter of general vs specific technique)

So - whether the `parser.html` is added here or not is a matter of choice.

...just a matter of another approach for interested parties...

Comment: I'll give this a whirl as I think it may be what I'm looking for. I may have questions for you as I'm not the best at batch. Standby...

Comment: Ok so this is pretty darn close to what I'm looking to achieve. Let me add that sometimes after `_ABC_` there may be an additional word that needs to be captured -- since I'm not the best at batch where would I change that in the code you supplied, I tried a couple of places but can't get it.

Comment: You realise, of course, that ther'll be an extra charge for changing the spec?

Comment: +1, but why you can't perform string operations directly on metas? [example](http://pastebin.com/xNQ1vjxC)

Comment: Your example is substringing using the values in metavariables, not attempting to use a form like `%%a:~3,2` to extract the 4th&5th characters of `%%a`. To do that, you have to assign `%%a` to an ordinary environment variable first - AFAIAA - I'd guess that the syntax requires a `%` or `!` bracket. How should `%%a:~3,2%` be interpreted? or `%%%a:~3,2%`? Messy. Also valid syntax, but not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Peter's answer really helped! I did do some modifications based on some additional use cases. Here is my answer....

```
@ECHO ON
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f "delims==" %%i IN ('set val 2^>nul') DO (SET %%i=)
FOR /f "tokens=1-5delims=_" %%a IN (filelist.txt) DO (
    IF "%%e"=="|" (
        SET val_%%d=!val_%%d!, %%a-%%b-%%c
    )   ELSE (
        SET val_%%d_%%e=!val_%%d_%%e!, %%a-%%b-%%c
    )
)

FOR /f "tokens=2-4delims=_=" %%i IN ('set val 2^>nul') DO (
    IF "%%k"=="" (
        SET list=%%j
        SET list=!list:~2!
        >%%i_parser.html ECHO ^<input type="text" name="trackingId" size="100" value = "!list!"^>
        ECHO generated %%i parser
    )   ELSE (   
        SET list=%%k
        SET list=!list:~2!
        >%%i_%%j_parser.html ECHO ^<input type="text" name="trackingId" size="100" value = "!list!"^>
        ECHO generated %%i_%%j parser
    )
)
```